# How check for a condition in ant and depending on its value print a message?

Tags: ant

This is a small piece of code please give a look at it then follow the description....

```
    <condition property="${param1}">
            <or>
                <istrue value="win-x86"/>
                <istrue value= "win-x86-client"/>
                <istrue value= "win-x64"/>
            </or>
     </condition>
    <target name="Mytarget" if="${param1}">
        <echo message="executing windows family build:::${param1}"/>
    </target>
<target name="print.name" >
    <antcall target="win-x86-build">
       <param name="param1" value="${platform.id}"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
```

I want that when ever platform.id contains any of the windows family name it should print the message `EXECUTING WINDOWS FAMILY BUILD` but the problem is that it is printing this message even when the family is unix.

I think either I am not checking the condition properly or else i am doing some other mistake.
Can someone help me out with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter is trying to explain that you must explicitly specify the property name. Try the following to make your code work:

```
<project name="demo" default="Mytarget">

    <condition property="windoze">
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${param1}" arg2="win-x86"/>
            <equals arg1="${param1}" arg2="win-x86-client"/>
            <equals arg1="${param1}" arg2="win-x64"/>
        </or>
    </condition>

    <target name="Mytarget" if="windoze">
        <echo message="executing windows family build:::${param1}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

A better solution would be to make use of operating system tests built into ANT's [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) task.

```
<project name="demo" default="Mytarget">

    <condition property="windoze">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </condition>

    <target name="Mytarget" if="windoze">
        <echo message="executing windows family build:::${os.name}-${os.arch}-${os.version}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 5):

Since ant 1.9.1 you can do this:

```
<project name="tryit" xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">
   <exec executable="java">
     <arg line="-X" if:true="${showextendedparams}"/>
     <arg line="-version" unless:true="${showextendedparams}"/>
   </exec>
   <condition property="onmac">
     <os family="mac"/>
   </condition>
   <echo if:set="onmac">running on MacOS</echo>
   <echo unless:set="onmac">not running on MacOS</echo>
</project>
```

Comment: use at least v1.9.3 - see also https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55885

Comment: This works great, thanks! In the context of Maven/pom.xml, the `xmlns` go onto the `target` when using `maven-antrun-plugin`: `<target xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you misunderstood the [Condition Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html):

> `property`: The name of the property to set.

Try using the [Condition`os`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html#os):

> Test whether the current operating system is of a given type.

Comment: i am passing my own value in platform.id and that i want to check if it is either of above three

Comment: Then try using [`equals` condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html#equals).

Comment: i think you people are not understanding my question,my program flow exactly same as above if platform.id contains any of the above three values then the message should be printed out. that is what i want my program to do

Comment: I think you people are not understanding my answer :) Your usage of condition is wrong. `property` is the name of the property to be set - **not** to be checked, and istrue checks, if the property with that name has a value like `true`, `yes` or `on`. You want to check for **specific values**, so equals is what you want. Documentation has perfect examples, so I am not going to write that code for you. Feel free to ask if you have troubles implementing.