# antcall based on a condition

Tags: ant, build, build-automation

This is what I am trying to achieve:

if a property is set then call antcall target. is this doable? can someone tell me how?

```
<condition>
    <isset property="some.property">
        <antcall target="do.something">
    </isset>
</condition>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How check for a condition in ant and depending on its value print a message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680982/how-check-for-a-condition-in-ant-and-depending-on-its-value-print-a-message)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<if>
    <isset property="some.property"/>
    <then>
        <antcall target="do.something"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

If then conditions require [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/), but so does just about anything useful in ant.

Comment: Great. Works for me. I am ok with Ant Contrib.

Comment: It should be <antcall target="do.something" />

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm really late to this but here is another way to do this if you are using an of ant-contrib where if doesn't support a nested antcall element (I am using antcontrib 1.02b which doesn't).

```
<target name="TaskUnderRightCondition" if="some.property">
  ...
</target>
```

You can further expand this to check to see if some.property should be set just before this target is called by using depends becuase depends is executed before the if attribute is evaluated.  Thus you could have this:

```
<target name="TestSomeValue">
  <condition property="some.property">
    <equals arg1="${someval}" arg2="${someOtherVal}" />
  </condition>
</target>

<target name="TaskUnderRightCondition" if="some.property" depends="TestSomeValue">
  ...
</target>
```

In this case TestSomeValue is called and, if someval == someOtherVal then some.property is set and finally, TaskUnderRightCondition will be executed.  If someval != someOtherVal then TaskUnderRightCondition will be skipped over.

You can learn more about conditions via [the documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html).

Comment: Can you do something like `<target name="TaskUnderRightCondition" if="${someval eq someOtherVal}" />`?

Comment: @siledh I don't know.  I don't think so.

Answer (score -1):

Consider also you can invoke groovy for these purposes:

```
<use-groovy/>
<groovy>
   if (Boolean.valueOf(properties["some.property"])) {
     ant.project.executeTarget("do.something")
   }
</groovy>
```